# Determining if two numbers are relatively prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let n be a positive integer. Then prove the relation of congruence mod n is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb{Z}$.

for the symmetric part of the proof, I have

Let $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$

Suppose $n | (a-b)$

```
 Since if two numbers are relatively prime $\exists x,y(ax+by=1)$

 & if x and y are relatively prime and $x | yq$ then $x|q$
```

From the two above theormes I get

Then $n | -1(b-a)$

The logic is that $b-a = q$ and that, $nx+(-1)y=1$ holds true for when $x=0$ and $y=-1$

Does this all seem correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to apply the boxed result you need two relatively prime numbers, which we do not have in this problem.

Instead, use the definition of "divides".  Because $n|(a-b)$, there is some integer $k$ such that $nk=a-b$.  Now, $n(-k)=b-a$.  $-k$ is an integer because $k$ is, so $n|(b-a)$.

Comment: why is -1 not relatively prime with n, if I found an x and y that sastifies the equation, for that condition though? Is it just because I don't know for sure that n does divide n(b-a)?

Comment: Okay, fine, $-1$ is relatively prime with $n$.  That doesn't help you at all, as the boxed equation might give you $-1(-1)+n(0)=1$; there is no reason that our specified $a,b$ must appear.